# Merging Cells automatically in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet where I'm checking column "B". In COlumn "B" starting from the 2nd row I have merged cells in this way, B2 is merged with B3, B4 is merged with B5 and B6 is merged with B7, etc...Is it possible to create a VBA loop in excel what will expand the mergings? I would like to have 5 merged cells in Column B, so this loop should insert 3 cells between B2 and B3, between B4 and B5 and etc... Is it possible? and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work - assuming no funkyness in the data or layout.

```
Sub insert_rows()
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Dim tmpRng As Range

Set tmpRng = Range("B" & lastRow)

Dim rowsToAdd As Long, i As Long
rowsToAdd = 3

Do While tmpRng.Rows(1).Row >= 2
    With tmpRng.Rows(2)
        For i = 1 To rowsToAdd
            .Insert shift:=xlDown, copyorigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Next i
    End With
    Set tmpRng = tmpRng.End(xlUp)
Loop
End Sub
```

Note it's inserting a row within column B. If you want an entire row inserted, then change the line to `With tmpRng.rows(2).EntireRow`